# не срабатывают проверки

Tags: php, html

мне кажется что чего-то не хватает в html коде, помогите кто знает.

```
<?php

    session_start();
    require_once 'connect.php';

//$login = htmlspecialchars($_POST['login']);//$_POST['login'];
//$email = htmlspecialchars($_POST['email']);//$_POST['email'];
//$password = htmlspecialchars($_POST['password']);//$_POST['password'];
//$password_confirm = htmlspecialchars($_POST['password_confirm']);//$_POST['password_confirm'];
 
if(!isset($_POST['login']) && !isset($_POST['email']) && !isset($_POST['password']) && !isset($_POST['password_confirm'])){ 

    $login = $_POST['login'];
    $email = $_POST['email'];
    $password = $_POST['password'];
    $password_confirm = $_POST['password_confirm'];
    
     if (empty($login)) {
        $_SESSION['message'] = "Вы не ввели логин";
        header('Location: ../register.php');
    
    } else if (empty($email)) {
        $_SESSION['message'] = "Вы не ввели email";
        header('Location: ../register.php');
    
    } else if (empty($password)) {
        $_SESSION['message'] = "Вы не ввели пароль";
        header('Location: ../register.php');
    
    } else if ($password_confirm != $password) {
        $_SESSION['message'] = "Пароли не совпадают";
        header('Location: ../register.php');
    } else {
       $query = "INSERT INTO users ( login, email, password) VALUES ( $login, $email, $password)";
       $result = mysqli_query($connection, $query);
       $_SESSION['message'] = "Регистрация прошла успешно";
       header('Location: ../index.php');
    }
    }
 ?>
```

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:100,100italic,300,300italic,regular,italic,500,500italic,700,700italic,900,900italic" rel="stylesheet" >
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="..\register_form\css\login.css">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="wrapper">
    <form action="..\register_form\vendor\signup.php" enctype="multipart/form-data" class="form__body" method="post">  
        <input type="text"  name="login" placeholder="Логин" class="login">
        <input type="e-mail"  name="email" placeholder="e-mail" class="email">
        <input type="password"  name="password" placeholder="Введите пароль"class="password">
        <input type="password"  name="password_confirm" placeholder="Подтвердите пароль"class="password">
        
        <button type="submit"  class="form__button"> Зарегистроваться </button>
        <p class="p_reg" >
            У вас есть аккаунт? - <a href ="..\index.php">авторизироваться</a>
        </p>
        
    </form>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: `!isset(` восклицательный знак зачем? проверьте ваше условие, в блок проверок по моему вы попадаете когда у вас НЕ определены $_POST переменные.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

попробуйте изменить условие входа в блок проверок на

```
if(isset($_POST['login'],$_POST['email'],$_POST['password'],$_POST['password_confirm']))
```

Comment: к сожалению не помогло, все также не выдает ошибок.

Comment: еще в html добавьте где-нибудь вывод $_SESSION['message']

Comment: я так понимаю вы привели html который генерит register.php, там надо добавить вывод этот

Comment: теперь работает, спасибо.